# Complex constructions with "will"

Tags: sentence

Can anyone tell me if all the forms mentioned below are correct? If not, which one sounds most natural?

> 1. We will wait for the parcel to arrive and reimburse you then.
> 2. We will wait for the parcel to arrive and will reimburse you then.
> 3. We will wait for the parcel to arrive and we will reimburse you then.

Comment: Why did you think any of them was wrong ?

Comment: I'm just confused if that's correct not to use "will" before "reimburse". In other words, does the "will" used before "wait" apply also to "reimburse" in the sentence 1? I mean, does it still have a reference to the future?

Comment: '_We will wait for the parcel to arrive and will then reimburse you_' is how I would put it, giving emphasis to the response 'then' once the parcel arrives.